# Migrating from MSSQL to postgresql OR mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, postgresql, migration

I am working on .NET environment.
Because of sql server express limitations (4gb max) I want to switch a free solution.
I am checking around and found out postgresql OR mysql would be great solution.

As I only worked on on MsSql, I want to learn which database would be easier for me to migrate all my existing data. 
Also which database syntax (postgresql OR mysql) is closer sql MsSql syntax and structure.
So I can learn it faster.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If the 4GB cap is the only thing driving your migration, the max database size has increased to 10GB for [Express Edition](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2011/06/meme-monday-for-june.html)

Comment: PostgreSQL syntax is very different because it follows the ANSI standard closely (which MS does not). MySQL is very different because it does not follow the ANSI standard (and has less features)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm... you will find language differences in either of those. I had that same choice a while ago and ended going to MySql due to its immense comunity.

Of course, if your only reason is the 4gb limitation I would not recommend switching (but that's just me). You should upgrade to SQL 2008 / 2012 which they both have 10gb limitation. Also, if you must know, there are other limitations such as using only 1 processor and I believe there's a RAM restriction as well. Anyway it shouldn't make a noticeable difference with small databases (<10g) and not-so-complicated queries.

If you want help in migrating from MSSQL to MySQL you should google for something like "MSSQL to MySQL Migration Toolkit" (I did that). It's fairly easy, you'll make the transition in no-time and most likely without any problems.

Best of luck

Answer (score 2):

MySQL Workbench has a migration wizard. Is has some prerequisites for MS SQL, which are explained very clearly in the wizard help docs.
http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/